# ant-design theme switcher in NextJs

Tags: next.js, antd, next.js13

I'am new in NextJs and I'm trying to use it with ant-design having `dark/light` themes, however a faced the issue:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "ant-input css-dev-only-do-not-override-yqr998 ant-input-outlined" Client: "ant-input css-dev-only-do-not-override-zl9ks2 ant-input-outlined"
```

As I see it, the antd components initialized on the server with "default" theme (as set theme cannod be red from client side ofc), but it was changed on the client side od first page load, however antd component remain with classneme for server side theme. More or less... However, when I navigate next page, this seems to be fixed and antd sets component classes correctly basing on client side theme.

I use components structure as below:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
export const AppThemeProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => (
  <ThemeProvider attribute="class">{children}</ThemeProvider>
);


export const Component = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { defaultAlgorithm, darkAlgorithm } = theme;
  const { theme: currentTheme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  const algorithm = useMemo(
    () => (currentTheme === "dark" ? darkAlgorithm : defaultAlgorithm),
    [currentTheme, darkAlgorithm, defaultAlgorithm]
  );

  return <ConfigProvider theme={{ algorithm }}>{children}</ConfigProvider>;
};

<AppThemeProvider>
    <Component />
</AppThemeProvider>
```

the `currentTheme` is set correctly always on client side, but still, antd components has wrong classname set on init.

So I found workaround for that (adding it to ):

```
const themeFixer = new Map([
  ["dark", "light"],
  ["light", "dark"],
]);

const defaultTheme =
  typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? localStorage.getItem("theme") ?? "dark"
    : "dark";

 useEffect(() => {
    const nextTheme = themeFixer.get(currentTheme) ?? defaultTheme;
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTheme(nextTheme);
    }, 10);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setTheme(themeFixer.get(nextTheme)!);
    }, 20);
  }, []);
```

Not so sophisticated but it works :)

So the question is, is there any better solution for that, is there any good practice for that case?